# When I use bluej to try and return values higher than my target value from my Array List it says Error: <identifier> expected

Tags: java, bluej

This is the code I'm trying to use in Bluej to return values higher than my target value:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BiggestValue
{
    public ArrayList<Integer> getBiggerValues (int target, ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
        for (int ix=0; ix < list.size(); ix++)
        {
            int currentItem = list.get(ix);
            if (currentItem > target)
            {
                result.add (currentItem);
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

It compiles but when I put in values to get the result I get the following message:

[image]

can anyone help?
Thanks
Lydia

Comment: The problem is not in the code you've posted but in the code that _invokes_ `getBiggerValues()`.  Please [edit] your post and add that code.

Comment: you should pass an arraylist object in the second parameter

Comment: Sorry I'm so new to this, how do I pass and arraylist object in the second parameter?

Comment: Hi Jim, I'm sorry that code is everything that I have, I then just compile it and create a new object in bluej and then right click which brings up a menu then I click on ArrayList<Integer> getBiggerValues (int target, ArrayList<Integer> list)

Comment: Worth checking the [Stack Overflow HomeWork Wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to see if any of it applies to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{14, 19, 20}))` as the second parameter or you could write a `main` method as shown below:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    BiggestValue bV = new BiggestValue();
    ArrayList bigs = bV.getBiggerValues(17, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{14, 19, 20})));
    //methods to display the output.
}
```